# Can't run simple ui-router app (anglularJs Ui-Router)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-ui-router

I just started studying [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/) but I can not make it work since I get some errors in the consol. I don't understand what the error says therefore I decided to ask for help here.

First little bit of intro. I am using node.js server. 
The root directory of the server looks like this

- *node_modules/*
- *a01.js*
- *index.html*
- *main.js*

I also installed [ui-router npm package](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) on the server side.

The file I run on the server is **main.js** and it looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.listen(80);
console.log("App is listening on port 80")
```

This is **index.htm**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="a01.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <a href="#/first-msg">FirstMessage</a>
    <div ui-view>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is **a01.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  // body...
  $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
    url: '/first-msg',
    template: '<strong> This is first message!</strong>' 
  })
}])
```

And here is the error I get into the browser's console: [error-link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:6:425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:26:270%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:25:299)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:26:44%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:42:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:7:495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:41:476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:46:44)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:21:373)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Sc%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js:22:179) and this is how it looks like:

[image: Browser console error]

Some ideas?

Comment: `app !== myApp` . Also extra quote in script tag and typo in spelling `$stateProvider`

Comment: @charlietfl
Thank you for your notes. I fixed (and edited in the post) the code according your notes, but still have this error and the template doesn't appear in the view.

Comment: My guess would be, that the browser is not able to GET the a01.js File, because the server only replies to the / path. Please take a look at the network tab in your dev tools.

Comment: @Oliver 
May be you are right? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rNxPxT5x-xAe1A5AGcVUyihS53KAIxR/view?usp=sharing  But angular js is with status pending. Does it mean that there is an issue as well?

Comment: You might wanna try to add `app.get('/a01.js', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/a01.js");
});` to your server code.

Comment: @Oliver The error disappeared and the page loads just fine, But when I click on the link I don't get the view displayed. I am following this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGhc8E-L2G0&t=1630s) tutorial  but I don't get the same result.